# Convert all colums in the rows from date to timestamp MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, timestamp

I have a database with 13000 rows. Each row contains the column 'date' which is now in this format (example): `2012-09-01 17:53:28`, but I want them to be a TIMESTAMP.

What query should I run to update all columns named 'date'  from date to timestamp on all rows?

Thanks

Comment: If the dates are stored in the same fashion as you state, i.e. **`2012-09-01 17:53:28`**, then you can simply use `ALTER TABLE \`tbl\` CHANGE COLUMN \`date\` \`date\` TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty straightforward to convert from one type to another using the [ALTER TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html) command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE old_date new_timestamp TIMESTAMP
```

This process may take a while to complete if you have a lot of data and a large number of indexes.

I'm not sure why you'd want to switch these to the `TIMESTAMP` type as that has a much more limited range than `DATETIME`. The differences are [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) and important to know.

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear what you are asking for. There exist following datatypes: `date`, `time`, `datetime` and `timestamp`. And there's `UNIX_TIMESTAMP`, which is the seconds since 1970-01-01, but I don't think that's what you're after.

I suggest you read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html).

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
>
> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and
>   time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to
>   '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.

When you want to convert your column `date` do:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable MODIFY COLUMN yourDateColumn TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-09-01 17:53:28');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function to return values as timestamp when doing a query. Like so:

```
mysqli_query("select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) as date from table");
```

Comment: Why does this answer have `mysql_query` in it?

Comment: OP seems to be using mysql because have it on the title and one of its tags, just guessing he is using that function.

Comment: Well, `mysqli` is admittedly an improvement, but the original question doesn't have anything to do with PHP.